# Bessel type function?

Tags: number-theory

The matrix below

$\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & \dots\\
\frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & \dots\\
\frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{3} & \dots\\
\frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{4} & 0 & 0 & 0 & \dots\\
\frac{1}{5} & \frac{1}{5} & \frac{1}{5} & \frac{1}{5} & \frac{1}{5} & 0 & 0 & \dots\\
\frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{6} & 0 & \dots\\
\frac{1}{7} & \frac{1}{7} & \frac{1}{7} & \frac{1}{7} & \frac{1}{7} & \frac{1}{7} & \frac{1}{7} & \dots\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots\\
\end{array}
\right)$

follows a pattern whereby the first line begins $\{1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0\dots\}$

the second: $\{\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},0,0,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},0,0,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},0,0\dots\}$

the third: $\{\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{3},0,0,0,\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{3},0,0,0\dots\}$

and so on.

Summing the first $m$ rows together and subtracting $\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^{m}\frac{1}{k}$ from each element from the resultant array gives a sequence of numbers that fluctuates between positive and negative values. The resultant cummulative plot looks like this:

[image]

```
y = 3000; m = 500;
ListPlot[Accumulate[Total[Take[Flatten[ConstantArray
[#,Ceiling[(y)/Length@#]]], y] & /@ Table[Join[ConstantArray[1/row, row], 
ConstantArray[0, row]], {row, 1, m}]] - Sum[1/k, {k, 1, m}]/2]]
```

where $y$ is the number of columns, and $m$ the number of rows, and is apparently scalable by dividing by $\dfrac{m}{4}$:

[image]

Is it true that this is related to the family of [Bessel functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function) (inclusive of [trigonometric integrals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_integral), which are related to [spherical Bessel functions](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SphericalBesselFunctionoftheFirstKind.html))?

Below is a plot of a [Bessel function of the second kind](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BesselFunctionoftheSecondKind.html), for illustrative purposes:

[image]

given by

$$
Y_0(z)=\dfrac{2}{\pi}\bigg(\bigg(\log(z/2)+\gamma\bigg)\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{(-1)^m}{m!\ \Gamma(m+1)}(z/2)^{2m}+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{k+1}\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{i}\bigg(\dfrac{(z^2/4)^k}{(k!)^2}\bigg)\bigg)
$$

Whether it is the case or not, I would be interested to know why it follows this pattern. The periodicity up to $y$ follows a particular type of randomness, seen also in the differences between zeta zeros, for example. I am curious to find out whether there is any connection.

## Update

[image]

plotted with this (ridiculously long) [piecewise code](http://pastebin.com/efNt5duW), thanks to [Ruslan](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/64206/ruslan)'s answer below.

Comment: Are there any reasons for a Bessel type function or is it just the shape of the curve? $Y_0$ has a logarithmic singularity at $z=0$. A similiar shape without singularity is e.g. the [Fresnel cos integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_integral).

Comment: BTW, your code sums first $m$ columns not rows.

Comment: Ah, yes, it sums *across* the columns, for the first $m$ rows. Sorry, should have made that clearer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is unlikely to be related to Bessel functions or Fresnel integral or sine/cosine integral. Let's take your code, assigning the `ListPlot` argument to variable `data`:

```
y = 3000; m = 500;
data = Accumulate[
   Total[Take[Flatten[ConstantArray[#, Ceiling[(y)/Length@#]]], y] & /@
       Table[Join[ConstantArray[1/row, row], 
        ConstantArray[0, row]], {row, 1, m}]] - 
    Sum[1/k, {k, 1, m}]/2];
ListPlot[data]
```

[image]

Now we'd need to smooth this somewhat. Let's use a moving average with e.g. 30 points:

```
smdata = ListConvolve[#/Total[#] &@Table[1., {i, 1, 30}], data];
ListPlot[smdata, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Now this looks somewhat more tractable by differentiating, although it does have some noise, we can still see some structure in the derivative. For this, make an interpolation:

```
di = Interpolation[smdata];
```

And plot the derivative of the interpolant:

```
Plot[di'[x], {x, 1, First@Dimensions@data - 500}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

We can see that the derivative may even have some cusps at its extrema, so it doesn't look like a smooth function, which would be if it were a Bessel function or Fresnel integral or anything supposed in the comments.

The plot, however, gives some ideas. What if it's just "broken" and (quasi)periodically reflected? Let's try adding `-0.45-di'[x]` to the plot:

```
Plot[{di'[x], -0.45 - di'[x]}, {x, 1, First@Dimensions@data - 500}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

This seems to smoothly fit the guess. I think we could do the similar thing with other cusps and recover something like a logarithmic function. Here're some more added plots:

```
Plot[{di'[x], -0.45 - di'[x], di'[x] - 0.70, -0.85 - di'[x], di'[x] - 1}, {x, 1, 
  First@Dimensions@data - 500}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Defining a piecewise function, we can plot the single curve:

```
pw[x_] = Piecewise[{
    {di'[x], x < 500},
    {-0.45 - di'[x], x < 1000},
    {di'[x] - 0.70, x < 1500},
    {-0.85 - di'[x], x < 2000},
    {di'[x] - 1, True}}];
Plot[pw[x], {x, 1, First@Dimensions@data - 500}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Now, more interesting. Let's define analytically what we get. First, we can notice that our matrix can be generated by the following function:

$$f(x,y)=\frac1{2y}\left\{1+\text{sgn}\left[\sin\left(\frac{\pi x}y-\varepsilon\right)\right]\right\},$$

where to get the matrix we should take $\lim_{\varepsilon\to+0}$ and use $x,y=1,2,...$.

Now, we aren't interested in any pixellation noise, so we can switch from taking sums to taking integrals, and from matrix to the generator function itself. Then we don't have to bother with $\varepsilon$, and can set $\varepsilon=0$. Now the sum over column index $y$ and subtracting the sum over $\frac1k$ will give us a function of row index $x$:

$$s(x)=\int_1^m\frac1{2y}\text{sgn}\left(\sin\frac{\pi x}y\right)\text{d} y,$$

where $m$ is the same as `m` in your code.

Now, taking $y=300$, $m=50$, I get the resulting $s(x)$:
[image]

Here, at, e.g. $x=30$, we have:

$$s(30)=-\frac12\left(\log\frac35+\sum_{n=2}^{30}(-1)^n \log\frac n{n-1}\right).$$

Similar expressions in terms of logarithms are for other $x$ values.

So, the correct description of the function is in terms of simple logarithms. Then the function which you thought as Bessel-related, being an integral of this function, is also expressible in terms of logarithms.

Note however, that the function isn't really smooth. See it magnified:

[image]

Comment: A fantastic answer! It is surprising what lurks beneath! :) Presumably this would rule out any connection alluded to in the closing paragraph of the question? Or is it still possible that this is a partial sum mimicry of the behaviour seen in the zeta zero spacings?

Comment: It seems `Exp[-pw[x]]^2` may be a straight line, suggesting the function might be like `-Log[Sqrt[x/310]]`.

Comment: I should be interested to know how the pair correlation function of the zeta zeros behaves when given a similar treatment.

Comment: I have just had a thought though, that interpolating data might not be altogether accurate - especially with the limited data (that is calculable on my machine at least). It is surely liable to the shortfalls of abstracting data to the $n$th degree? Is this a possible issue with this approach?

Comment: What do you mean? Interpolation here doesn't have to be any accurate, we could just as easily have used finite differences differentiation. The main aim I pursued was simplicity of code. Precision is of no sense since the data is noisy itself.

Comment: My point is that by introducing any sort of randomness or fuzziness may be liable to data being interpreted as having "cusps" - I have tried to illustrate what I mean below.

Comment: `data = Table[(Evaluate[BesselY[0, x]] + 0)/2 + 1, {x, 0, 20, 0.3}]; p = Drop[data, 1]; q = RandomReal[{-0.01, 0.01}, 1][[1]] & /@ Range@Length[Drop[data, 1]]; data1 = p + q; dib1 = Interpolation[ data1]; Plot[{-If[x < 13, dib1'[x], If[x < 24, -0.13 - dib1'[x], If[x < 35, dib1'[x] - 0.22, If[x < 45, -0.3 - dib1'[x], If[x < 54, dib1'[x] - 0.36]]]]] + 0.5}, {x, 2, 65}, PlotRange -> All]`

Comment: `Plot[{dib1'[x], -0.13 - dib1'[x]}, {x, 1, 65}, PlotRange -> All]`

Comment: And, of course, as the aspect ratio is changed, so the cusps become more or less prominent (try `Plot[{dib1'[x], -0.13 - dib1'[x]}, {x, 1, 65}, PlotRange -> All, 
 AspectRatio -> 2]`, for example). The cusps in your answer are particularly prominent, however - I am just not sure how scientific an approach this is, though. - Just a thought, really.

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: A wonderful answer - thank you.  Could I just ask you to elaborate on how the matrix is generated by the function you give?

Comment: `Table[f[X,Y],{X,1,y},{Y,1,m}]` (`y` and `m` are your values), and I took $\varepsilon=10^{-10}$ for my experiments. For larger matrices you may want to make $\varepsilon$ even smaller.

Comment: Don't forget that you have defined `y` as a number. And it also appears as formal parameter of `f` in this code.

Comment: See [this screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/gJOZhYk.png)

Comment: eventually eked out some sort of piecewise function for the original plot! - see update :)