# Bessel function sum?

Tags: number-theory, bessel-functions

Is

$$f(x)=\dfrac{2\pi}{n^2}\sum_{m=1}^{x}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\dfrac{\Im(e^{\dfrac{\pi i m}{\Im(\rho_k)}})k}{\Im(\rho_k)}$$

related to the Bessel family of functions?

Plot for $n=300$

[image]

Or is it related to the $sin$ integral as [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/818933/bessel-type-function)?

(NB, when $k$ replaces $\Im(\rho_k)$, output is similar, but different scale.)

Comment: What is $\Im(\rho_k)$?

Comment: Imaginary part of kth Zeta zero

Comment: Why do you think it might be related to Bessel functions?

Comment: I have just realised it is basically a sine integral